# How to make/find a program that parses a web page and texts me when it finds something

Tags: technology

I want to make or find a program that does the following:

1. it logs into a webpage with username and password
2. it parses a page (I'm interested in a table, with changing number of rows) every 15 seconds let's say
3. when it finds a number > a given value, it texts me on my phone.

The thing is that I don't know where to start or what keywords to even use to look this stuff up. Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Hi GBProg, Welcome to Lifehacks. We hope you enjoy your time here sharing knowledge and experience. You already have such a program and it works as you described. In your Web browser under the Edit menu is "Find." Use that and its specific refinements to get the "something" you enter into the search field. Your answer appears in text. Have fun. Good luck.

Comment: You might be able to do that with IFTTT webhooks, but if not you'd need to hire a programmer to do that. If you want to learn, the key word to search for is screen scraping.

Comment: Go to fiverr.com or another freelancer site if you want to hire someone to do it for you. It's not a very big job for someone who knows what they're doing.

Comment: On linux you could run a cronjob with wget and open the download table with cat and pipe it to grep...something like this run from terminal:
wget www.yourfavoritewebsite.com
cat yourfile | grep "what your interested"
mail -s "Test Subject" user@example.com < /dev/null

Syntax not exact just to give you an idea...If you run this as cronjob you can let this commands be executed in arbitrary time intervals...